# Is there a shortcut to select words in Visual Studio Community that is like VSCode/Atom?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio

On VSCode and Atom there is the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> that selects the word occurrence.

Is there something similar on Visual Studio Community/Pro/... ?

Answer (score 1):

The default shortcut for this behavior has been changed (as of September 2020) to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

For anyone looking to change this keybinding, the keyboard shortcut command is called `editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch`, and the `when` key should be `editorFocus`.

From the default `keybindings.json` file in VSCode:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+d",
  "command": "editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch",
  "when": "editorFocus"
}
```

Comment: That's useful, but it is not exactly like `ctrl+d`. On VSCode I can select the word in multiple places (multiple cursors).

Comment: You are correct, @BrunoLM, thank you for calling this out. I've updated my answer with the command you're referencing and the one the OP was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is what you want.